# WebAPI ODATA, How to convert SingleResult<BaseType> to SingleResult<DeriveType>

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, visual-studio-2013

I get from the server always the base type and I want to return the derive type. Do I have a way? I tried return (SingleResult)X but it didn't work.

Code:

```
GisImageLayer entity = (GisImageLayer)_LINQ.GisLayerQuery.FirstOrDefault(c => c.LayerType == EGisLayerType.ImageLayer & c.LayerID == key); 
return SingleResult.Create(new List(){entity}.AsQueryable());
```

Comment: Please show the code you currently have.

Comment: GisImageLayer entity = (GisImageLayer)_LINQ.GisLayerQuery.FirstOrDefault(c => c.LayerType == EGisLayerType.ImageLayer & c.LayerID == key);
            return SingleResult.Create(new List<GisImageLayer>() { entity }.AsQueryable<GisImageLayer>());

Comment: It would be better for you to add the code to the question and to include details of the derived type/base type.